# Participating in Imagine and/or Hackathon without attending

Tags: discussion

What are some good ways for someone to participate in the Hackathon prior to Imagine without actually being in attendance?

I will be at Imagine, but I don't arrive in Vegas until Monday morning, yet I would like to try and participate if possible.

Aside from that (and to keep the question a bit more relevant for other users), what are some good ways to participate in Imagine without being in attendance?